# Mask user input with asterisks

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to implement a simple input mask js which will replace asterisks for any sensitive user data on the form like the social#. However, this might sound like a very stupid question, when i want to submit the form, i want to send the actual value of the textfield, the user entered. How do i go about doing that? I want to avoid submitting asterisks as the textfield value

```
function mask(str) {
    if(str.value!=null || str.value!="") {
        num = str.value.length;
        var masked = "";
        for(i=0; i<num; i++) {
            masked = masked + "*";
        }
    document.getElementById(str.id).value = masked;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`<input type="password" />` will do this for you automatically, no need to reinvent the wheel

---

Given your feedback, what about a middle-road?  Keep the input box visible until text has been entered, then hide the input box when it loses focus and show a UI element to allow the user to bring the box back if needed.

---

[Here's a quick proof-of-concept](http://jsfiddle.net/KLnHB/)

Comment: yea type=password was my initial recommendation, however the user exp team did not like the fact that users when they enter their SSN are not able to see what they type